# How can I operate "Find & Replace" using only the keyboard in Pages for OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, pages, word-processor

When I have clicked <kbd>Tab</kbd> to highlight the **Replace All** button, <kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't do anything. Do I absolutely have to use the mouse for this?

It's inefficient to move between the keyboard and mouse when carrying out a long sequence of "Find & Replace" actions.

This is Pages 5.0 (1465) running on Yosemite.

Comment: As far as I know "clicking" the highlighted button is perormed with the Space Bar not the Enter key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Spacebar <kbd>Space</kbd> to click the selected button (not the Enter key <kbd>Enter</kbd>). That should do it for you.

(Note to editors: I want to have the word "Spacebar" in there in case someone searches for it.)